# Making a letter extend down the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a table of contents on my website and I had an idea to do something like this:

https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2f/79/65/2f79656f58bb598e873fbf6632991ac9.jpg

I like how the T extends down and they number the sections and put the title around it. How would I go about doing this?

I tried using an < hr > tag with this css:

```
.contentLine{
        border: 1px solid white;
        background: white;
        width: 2px;
        height: 200px
    }
```

This makes a straight up and down line like I want but I don't know how or even if it would be possible to attach it to the word Contents that i have on my page. I don't want to use the position: absolute; tag either. I want my website to be scaleable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no way to extend a part of an alphabet, what you want could be achieved by making use of ::before and ::after pseudo-elements.

```css
.content{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:55px;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-weight:700;
}
.t{
  position:relative;
  font-size:35px; /*Control the overall T size*/
}
.t::before{
  content:'';
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:-50%;
  top:-50%;
  background-color:black;
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
.t::after{
  content:'';
  height:1000%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  left:-50%;
  top:0%;

}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  conten&nbsp;<span class="t">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with instead of using the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements, I created an hr element that aligns with the t and runs down the page. Here is a link to the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/atomic-programmer/pen/LYPbGey).

```css
html {
  font-family: verdana;
  max-width: 99%;
  height: 200%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

hr {
  /*Rotates hr*/
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  /*Coloring*/
  border-color: black;
  background-color: black;
  /*Defining Position*/
  position: relative;
  left: -153.26px;
  height: 3.3px;
  top: 185px;
  width: 459px;
  /*Defining Padding/margins and overflow*/
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#num {
  /*Lets you play around with number and description offset*/
  margin-top: 20px;
  /*Defining left offset*/
  z-index: -10;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#desc {
  /*Lets you play around with number and description offset*/
  margin-top: -50px;
  /*Defining left offset*/
  z-index: -10;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#bd {
  display: flex;
}

#title {
  /*Defining bottom & left offset*/
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

#title1 {
  /*Defining bottom & left offset*/
  margin-left: 140px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#other {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h1>CONTENT</h1>
<hr>
<div id="bd">
  <div id="num">
    <h2>1</h2>
    <h2>2</h2>
    <h2>3</h2>
    <h2>4</h2>
    <h2>5</h2>
    <h2>6</h2>
    <h2>7</h2>
    <h2>8</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="desc">
    <h2 id="title">Book One: The Coming</h2>
    <h2 id="title1">Of The Martians</h2>
    <h2>Longer Description 1</h2>
    <h2>Description 2</h2>
    <h2>Longer Description 3</h2>
    <h2>Description 4</h2>
    <h2>Longer Description 5</h2>
    <h2>Description 6</h2>
    <h2>Longer Description 7</h2>
    <h2>Description 8</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="other">
  <h1>Other Page Content</h1>
</div>
```